# Powershell 2.0 scheduled tasks - only include specific task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm using Powershell to report on scheduled task status.

Due to having to work with powershell 2.0 in this instance on Windows Server 2008R2, I am unable to use the get-scheduled task cmdlet, so I am using the below instead:

```
$sched = New-Object -Com "Schedule.Service"
$sched.Connect()
$out = @()
$sched.GetFolder("\").GetTasks(0) | % {
    $xml = [xml]$_.xml
    $out += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        "Name" = $_.Name
        "Status" = switch($_.State) {0 {"Unknown"} 1 {"Disabled"} 2 {"Queued"} 3 {"Ready"} 4 {"Running"}}
        "NextRunTime" = $_.NextRunTime
        "LastRunTime" = $_.LastRunTime
        "LastRunResult" = $_.LastTaskResult
        "Author" = $xml.Task.Principals.Principal.UserId
        "Created" = $xml.Task.RegistrationInfo.Date
    }
}

## pipe results to screen

$out | fl Name,Status,NextRuNTime,LastRunTime,LastRunResult,Author,Created
```

I'm then exporting to csv before importing and e-mailing.

The problem is that the script is also including the scheduled task I'm using to run this powershell command.

Is it possible to use schedule.service and include only a specific named scheduled task in the output, rather than all scheduled tasks? In this case the only task I wish to output is called 'Axway'.
Thanks

Comment: `Where { !($_.Name -in $ExcludedTaskList) }`?

Comment: Thanks - would you be able to show me whereabouts that where statement would go? 
I'm more used to `get-scheduledtask` so I'm a bit lost here